# Find the range of $ f(x)=9^x - 3^x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> **Problem**:-Find range of function $ f(x)=9^x - 3^x+1$, here the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$.
>
> **Solution**: $ f(x)=9^x - 3^x+1$. Let $f(x)=y$. Then 
>   $$ \begin{split}y&=9^x - 3^x+1\\
>  y&=3^{2x} - 3^x+1
> \end{split}$$
>   Let $3^x= u$. Then $ y=u^2 - u+1$, so
>   $$ u^2 - u+1-y=0.$$

Am I doing right?

Comment: looks like range is greater than or equal to 3/4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks good. To finish it off, we complete the square and notice that:
$$
y = u^2 - u + 1 = \left(u^2-u+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)+\dfrac{3}{4} = \left(u-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{3}{4} \ge 0+\dfrac{3}{4}=\dfrac{3}{4}
$$
since the square of any real number must be nonnegative. Hence, the range is:
$$
\{y\in \mathbb{R} \mid y \ge3/4\}
$$

Comment: Great,thanks a lot

Comment: @rst Though it doesn't matter here, when considering the quadratic, you should keep in mind that $u\ge0$.

Comment: Yeah,  I got your point

Comment: Erm... I meant $u>0$.

Answer (score 7):

After some computation, you will get $$f(x)=(3^x-1/2)^2+3/4.$$